# Is it possible to open VSCode and execute command in its internal terminal from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I know I can open VSCode via terminal just like this:

```
code .\path
```

And I can run desired commands in the same terminal (PowerShell in my case):

```
code .\path; cd .\path; npm run dev
```

But I would like to perform those commands in the VSCode terminal just to keep my workspace clean. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Oh, wow, didn't know about that, thank you. And yeah, it kinda does. But as a result of that approach, tasks will be executed every time I open VSCode, which is not great.

Comment: If you don't want to always run the task, you may edit the "tasks.json" file using PowerShell (e. g. rename a property so it doesn't run). Another idea: Check an environment variable in the task command: `if($env:EnableNpmTask -eq 'yes'){ npm run dev }`. Then before calling `code`, set the env var to enable the command: `$env:EnableNpmTask = 'yes'`